# ttk, How to position heading inside Labelframe instead of on the border?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to create an own ttk Theme based on my company's CI. I took the [Sun Valley theme](https://github.com/rdbende/Sun-Valley-ttk-theme) as starting point and swapped out graphics, fonts and colors.

However I am stuck on the Label frame. I am trying to position the Label *within* the frame, kind of like a heading. I.e. there should be some margin between top edge and label, and appropriate top-padding for the content (child widgets).

Now:

```
+-- Label ------
| ...
```

Desired:

```
+---------------
| Label
| ...
```

I tried to set the `padding` option:

- within the Layout
- on TLabelframe itself
- on TLabelframe.Label

but the label did not move a pixel. How to achieve this?

Generally I am very confused about what identifiers and options are legal within `ttk:style layout`, `ttk:style element` and `ttk:style configure`, because documentation is hazy and scattered all over the 'net, and there are no error messages whatsoever. Any helpful tips?

Edit: What I found out since posting:

- The Labelframe label is a separate widget altogether, with the class `TLabelframe.Label`.
- It is possible to override its layout and add a spacer on top, shifting the text down.
- However, the label widget is v-centered on the frame line. If its height increases, it pushes "upward" as much as downward. I found no way to alter the alignment w.r.t. to the actual frame.
- It might be possible to replace `Labelframe` altogether with a custom `Frame` subclass with the desired layout. But that means changing the "client" code in many places. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by changing the layout definitions so that the text element is held by the Labelframe layout and the Layoutframe.Label no longer draws the text element. Adding a bit of padding ensures the contained widgets leave the label clear.

[image: screenshot of example program running on Windows 10]

Example code:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class CustomLabelframe(ttk.Labelframe):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        """Initialize the widget with the custom style."""
        kwargs["style"] = "Custom.Labelframe"
        super(CustomLabelframe, self).__init__(master, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def register(master):
        style = ttk.Style(master)
        layout = CustomLabelframe.modify_layout(style.layout("TLabelframe"), "Custom")
        style.layout('Custom.Labelframe.Label', [
            ('Custom.Label.fill', {'sticky': 'nswe'})])
        style.layout('Custom.Labelframe', [
            ('Custom.Labelframe.border', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                ('Custom.Labelframe.text', {'side': 'top'}),
                ('Custom.Labelframe.padding', {'side': 'top', 'expand': True})
            ]})
        ])
        if (style.configure('TLabelframe')):
            style.configure("Custom.Labelframe", **style.configure("TLabelframe"))
        # Add space to the top to prevent child widgets overwriting the label.
        style.configure("Custom.Labelframe", padding=(0,12,0,0))
        style.map("Custom.Labelframe", **style.map("TLabelframe"))
        master.bind("<<ThemeChanged>>", lambda ev: CustomLabelframe.register(ev.widget))
        
    @staticmethod
    def modify_layout(layout, prefix):
        """Copy a style layout and rename the elements with a prefix."""
        result = []
        for item in layout:
            element,desc = item
            if "children" in desc:
                desc["children"] = HistoryCombobox.modify_layout(desc["children"], prefix)
            result.append((f"{prefix}.{element}",desc))
        return result


class App(ttk.Frame):
    """Test application for the custom widget."""
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super(App, self).__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.master.wm_geometry("640x480")
        
        frame = self.create_themesframe()
        frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH)
        
        for count in range(3):
            frame = CustomLabelframe(self, text=f"Frame {count}", width=160, height=80)
            frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
            button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Test")
            button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    def create_themesframe(self):
        frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Theme: ")
        themes = ttk.Combobox(frame, values=style.theme_names(), state="readonly")
        themes.current(themes.cget("values").index(style.theme_use()))
        themes.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda ev: style.theme_use(ev.widget.get()))
        label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        themes.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        return frame


def main(args=None):
    global root, app, style
    root = tk.Tk()
    style = ttk.Style(root)
    CustomLabelframe.register(root)
    app = App(root)
    try:
        import idlelib.pyshell
        sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], "-n"]
        root.bind("<Control-i>", lambda ev: idlelib.pyshell.main())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    root.mainloop()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Comment: Wow, you did it :-D I didn't know that you can just add a ``.text element to the layout and it automagically gets the text. Is there any documentation page about what layout elements exist in ttk? I mean, besides the actual [source code](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/file?name=generic/ttk/ttkElements.c)...

Comment: re documentation - not really. But the design of ttk is to loosely couple visual elements to the widgets. So a layout that contains a text element will draw that element using data from the text property on the widgets. If you added 2 text elements, they'd both show the same text. Labelframe is looking for a child layout (called Label) but it is optional.

Comment: I did a writeup myself. Proposed it to tkdocs.com's author for inclusion, but no response so far. I now published it myself: [ttk-elements.rst](https://gist.github.com/loehnertj/ed5f67ed5c1edac37182223d2097feda)

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively easy to place `ttk.Labelframe` text below, on or above the relief graphic. This example uses the text attribute but `labelwidget` can also be used.
In order for the relief to be visible the background color of `Labelframe.Label` must be set to "".

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import ttk

message = "Hello World"

master = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(master)
style.theme_use(themename = "default")

actualFont = font.Font(
    family = "Courier New", size = 20, weight = "bold")
style.configure(
    "TLabelframe.Label", background = "", font = actualFont)

frame = ttk.LabelFrame(
    master, labelanchor = "n", text = message)
frame.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

def change_heading():
    if frame["text"][0] == "\n":
        frame["text"] = f"{message}\n"
    else:
        frame["text"] = f"\n{message}"

button = tk.Button(
    frame, text = "Change", command = change_heading)
button.grid(sticky = "nsew")

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you - I already tried a similar solution (inserting a transparent spacer in the layout above the label). Unfortunately, the label is still centered on the frame, which means there is significant "dead space" above the frame. Same happens with your solution. :-( Upvoted you anyways :-)

Comment: Yes I've been trying to remove the dead space above the text but so far no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the [source of the Labelframe widget](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/file?name=generic/ttk/ttkFrame.c&ci=tip), I found that:

- The label is either placed vertically-centered on the frame's border, or flush above it, depending on the `-labeloutside` config option. (for default `NW` anchor)
- i.e. by adding whitespace on top of the text by any means, the label box will extend upwards the same amount as downwards, creating a "dead space" above the frame.
- There might still be a way to get it "inside" by increasing the border width, but I couldn't get it to work.

I now used the labeloutside option to make a "tab-like" heading.

```
    # ... (define $images array much earlier) ...
    ttk::style element create Labelframe.border image $images(card2) \
        -border 6 -padding 6 -sticky nsew
    ttk::style configure TLabelframe -padding {8 8 8 8} -labeloutside 1 -labelmargins {2 2 2 0}
    ttk::style element create Label.fill image $images(header2) -height 31 -padding {8 0 16 0} -border 1
```

With suitable images, this is nearly what I was aiming for, only that the header does not stretch across the full frame width. Tkinter elements use a "9-patch"-like subdivision strategy for images, so you can make stretchable frames using the `-border` argument for `element create`.

Result is approximately this:

```
+-------------+
| Heading     |
+-------------+----------------+
| ...                          |
```